# Jquery Not letting Me Save My FULL Text. Only 1 Word

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following code that will check to see if the div text has change and if so then update the text in the mysql table. but when i try and add spaces in the text and it dont allow it to save every thing i have write. Can somebody help me out please

Thank you.

```
 <script>function save() {   
 var div_sN6VmIGq = $("#64").text();
 var html_sN6VmIGq = $("#64").html();
 var top_sN6VmIGq = $("input#sN6VmIGq_top").val();
 var left_sN6VmIGq = $("input#sN6VmIGq_left").val();
 if(div_sN6VmIGq == "Text Here"){
}else{
 $('#saveupdate').load('modulus/empty/actions.php?act=save_text&pid=1&div_id=64&div_txt='+html_sN6VmIGq+'&randval='+ Math.random());
 }

 }
 </script>
```

Comment: have you tried to see what query string `actions.php` is actually called with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to URLEncode your text:

JavaScript:

```
var html_sN6VmIGq = escape($("#64").html());
//now use your function for saving the item
```

PHP:

```
$decodedVar = urldecode($yourEncodedVarHere);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to call [`encodeURI`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp) on your somewhat bizarrely named variables:

```
$('#saveupdate').load('modulus/empty/actions.php?act=save_text&pid=1&div_id=64&div_txt='+encodeURI(html_sN6VmIGq)+'&randval='+ Math.random());
```

Also, note that the id `64` is invalid, per this comment from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp):

> [ids must] begin with a letter A-Z or a-z followed by: letters (A-Za-z),
>   digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and
>   periods (".").